# Proving $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} f(x^3)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital, epsilon-delta

My reasoning is: suppose both limits exist, $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = l$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x^3) = m$.

For the second limit, by the limit definition we have:

$$\forall\epsilon>0,\ \exists\delta,\ \forall x,\ 0<|x-0|<\delta \implies |f(x^3)-m|<\epsilon.$$

Next I claim that $0<|x|<\delta \iff 0<|x^3|<\delta^3=\delta_1$ (omitting the proof for brevity), so that $$\forall\epsilon>0,\ \exists\delta_1,\ \forall x,\ 0<|x^3|<\delta_1 \implies |f(x^3)-m|<\epsilon.$$

Now, by the limit definition, we have $\lim_{x^3\to 0} f(x^3) = m$, and by the theorem that a function cannot approach two different limits at some $a$, I conclude that $l=m$.

Changing $3$ to $n$ gives proof for any $n\in N$ (with the help  of $0<|x|<\delta \iff 0<|x^n|<\delta^n, n\in N$).

I that reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. I would have done it using composition of functions, but that's a matter of taste.

Comment: Here, you are supposing that both limits exist. But note that if $n$ is even, for example $n=2$, then it is possible for $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x^2)$ to exist, whereas $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ doesn't exist. An explicit example is $f(x) = \begin{cases}  1 & \text{if $x \geq 0$} \\ -1 & \text{if $x<0$}\end{cases}$. In this case, $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x^2) = 1$, while $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$ doesn't even exist (the left and right limits are $-1$ and $1$ respectively). So, for even $n$ all you can prove is that if $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x^n) = l$ exists, then $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x)$ also exists and equals $l$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for reply!

Comment: @peek-a-boo Interesting and important note, thanks.

Comment: That reasoning is correct although it can be heavily simplified by taking advantage of two facts: (1) the composition of continuous functions is continous and (2) $\lim f(x)=f(\lim x)$ when $f$ is continuous.